# SpriteKit - SKLightNode shadow blend mode

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit

I have 3 SKLightNodes each one with a light color: Red, Green and Blue. The effect that I want is the shadow generated by the SKLightNodes to have a blend mode. 
Xcode Simulator
[image: Xcode Simulator]

I did some photoshop examples.

This is the shadow current behavior:
[image: This is the shadow current behavior]

This is the shadow behavior desired:
[image: This is the shadow behavior desired:]

Is this possible to do in SpriteKit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Color space

Hi, first of all, please note that there are different Color Spaces.
The result of mixing 2 colors depends on the Color Space you want to use.

### RGB Color Space

With this space color you can represent the intersection of the 2 raylights.

In this case, when 2 colors are mixed, the intersection is brighter.

[image]

You can get this effect in SpriteKit using `blendMode = .add`.

Here's the full code.

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        let red = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 100)
        red.fillColor = .red
        red.blendMode = .add
        red.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        addChild(red)

        let green = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 100)
        green.fillColor = .green
        green.blendMode = .add
        green.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100)
        addChild(green)

        let blue = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 100)
        blue.fillColor = .blue
        blue.blendMode = .add
        blue.position = CGPoint(x: 87, y: 50)
        addChild(blue)
    }
}
```

And the result

[image]

### CMY Colorspace

This color space represents the real world scenario of mixing 2 fluids.
Now mixing to colors produce a new darker color.

[image]

You can get this effect in SpriteKit simply using `blendMode = .multiply` (and IO suggest a white background).

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        self.backgroundColor = .white

        let yellow = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 100)
        yellow.fillColor = .yellow
        yellow.blendMode = .multiply
        yellow.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        addChild(yellow)

        let cyan = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 100)
        cyan.fillColor = .cyan
        cyan.blendMode = .multiply
        cyan.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100)
        addChild(cyan)

        let magenta = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 100)
        magenta.fillColor = .magenta
        magenta.blendMode = .multiply
        magenta.position = CGPoint(x: 87, y: 50)
        addChild(magenta)

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, what I'm looking for is a way to set blendMode to a SKLightNode's shadowColor.